# How to enable fibers for the early release of the jdk-16 loom?

Tags: java, project-loom, virtual-threads

I've downloaded the early release version from https://jdk.java.net/loom/ and java starts but doing `Class.forName("java.lang.Fiber")` and `Class.forName("java.lang.FiberScope")` doesn't work. Is there a flag/jar that needs to be included?

Comment: First of all -- check that you actually run expected release of java, and not any other installed on your machine. For example, print `System.getProperty("java.version")`.

Comment: Also I didn't find any notion of `java.lang.Fiber` in the repository( https://github.com/openjdk/loom/search?q=fiber ), and usage examples propose thread builders with `.virtual()` method to work with green threads, so maybe you are looking for something that is not there (or may be it was there some time ago and got removed later)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "fiber" seems to have been changed to "virtual thread".

See 2020-10 interview with Brian Goetz, [at 31:00 on YouTube](https://youtu.be/S-YaMiN6yxk?t=1860) where he mentions the name change.

Look in the early-access Java 16 Javadoc for things like [`Thread.VirtualThreadTask`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/loom/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.VirtualThreadTask.html).

See *virtual threads* terminology used in [*JEP draft: Re-implement ThreadGroup*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8252885), created 2020-09-07.

See code discussed in [this 2020-05 article](https://blog.usejournal.com/project-loom-virtual-threads-in-java-371dccc88b0f) making calls like `Thread.startVirtualThread`. [May be out-of-date, I do not know.]

Answer (score 1):

It is a late answer but just to save some time, Since it is still the experimental feature you can use the same using the `--enable preview flag on` jshell`. Here is how I used it. [image]